# How to redirect a wordpress page to wp admin dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this "Register" page on my website. On this page I've checked first if user already login, then if its true redirect it to the wp admin dashboard. Here is my sample code.

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    //redirect to wp admin dashboard
}
else {
    //display the registration form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did correct code, here you can add in if condition

wp_redirect(home_url()); exit;